# Wait on function to complete

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, synchronous

In one of my functions I'm getting a document:

```
controller.retrieveDocument(documentID);
// here I want to some work after the document has finished loading
```

This is how the function is build up:

```
public async void retrieveDocument(string documentID){
    DocumentResult documentResult = await GetDocumentTask (documentID);
    // do some checks here
}
```

The called function does this:

```
private async Task<DocumentResult> GetDocumentTask (string documentID){

    try{
        loadingSpinner.show();
        documentResult = await Task.Run(() => manager.GetDocument (documentID));
        loadingSpinner.hide();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Now I want that if `retrieveDocument` has been finished I do some other work. The problem currently is that `retrieveDocument` is asynchronous and the other code is executed before the function has finished loading. There are two options which comes to my mind:

1. Wait on `retrieveDocument` somehow.
2. Make all synchronous.
3. Use a separate event in `retrieveDocument`

I don't know how I should wait on `retrieveDocument` like described in 1. I tried to make it synchronous but than the loading spinner is not correctly show. It seems that it waits on the webservice call and if it has been finished the spinner is shown shortly. But this introduces a kind of lag. If I use it asynchronously I don't get this behavior and the loading spinner is correctly shown. No. 3 is the option which seems to be the best, but how would the other options work?

What I'm missing here?

Comment: You can't. This is why you should NEVER use `public async void`.

Comment: @Aron: You mean `void` is the problem here? Should I return the document instead?

Comment: Change the sig to `public async Task`.

Comment: You want something like `async Task` instead of `async void` then a `return Task.FromResult(0);`

Comment: @AshleyMedway No. If the sig is `async Task` there is no need to `return Task.FromResult`. You CAN however return that for `public Task` sig, and is very useful when used with `TaskCompletionSource`.

Comment: @Aron: Now it works. Thank you. Perhaps you post a full answer which I can mark as excepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You either want to rewrite your function as...

```
public async Task retrieveDocument(string documentID){
    DocumentResult documentResult = await GetDocumentTask (documentID);
    // do some checks here
}
```

OR

```
public Task retrieveDocument(string documentID){
    Task<DocumentResult> documentResult = GetDocumentTask (documentID);
    // do some checks here
    return documentResult;
}
```

However you are likely to want the former.

You need to return a `Task`, as that is the object that wraps the concepts of, work in flight, as well as the completion event. `async` `await` is actually just very clever syntaxic sugar, with a few really cool libraries added in (mostly for error handling).

Comment: Worked for me a saved days of headache. Thanks